# What is the advantage / disadvantage of joining stations?

Tags: openttd

I am getting familiar joining stations. I usually have a railway station and 'not joined' bus stations around it. I transfer passengers from bus to railway station. Is it worth to join stations with ctrl-click? Is it any point after that to use busses?

Answer (score 3):

Joining stations between station types (such as a bus with an airport) allows a common pool of cargo types to be serviced by different transportation methods.

For example, you could have an airport that is next to a fairly large city. If the city is big enough, the airport's catchment zone will not cover much of the city. By attaching some bus terminals to that airport you can move in passengers from farther in the city and 'transfer' them at the airport. Your planes will then pick up those transferred passengers and make more money.

You can do the same for things like goods for multiple cities from one station. One central train station receives goods on transfer, and local buses transfer goods from the train station (via attached depots) to local depots. These are often called 'feeder' systems, since they will 'feed' at a more constant rate than a train will.

Comment: but why don't you join local depots to the central station too, and instead of transfere goods with busses, goods would be 'received automatically'

Comment: from short distance it is not worth to transfer 'phisically' passengers in, but join to main station, and  from longer distances, i.e. from surrounding cities with bus?

Comment: Yes you could bring in passangers from surrounding cities. Remember this is the ultimate sandbox type of game, there is no set way of doing it, neither are there goals to win and making money is very easy once you are familiar with the game. Do what you think looks nice, is fun or lucrative.

Comment: Janos, I was thinking of one central train station supplying three separate towns. If you do not use a feeder system only one of the towns might receive necessary supplies, and even then only when a train arrives. You would have to time your trains such that at least one arrives each time. With feeder systems you can more accurately handle timetables for necessary supplies.